# Unable to append dynamic-component to the dynamic anchor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm new Angular using Angular 6.0.0-beta.
I'm not able to append dynamic-component to the dynamic anchor as explained below: -

I have placed anchor(appContent) like this in html: -

```
    <mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-tab-group class="tab-group" (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)">
            <mat-tab *ngFor="let obj of tags">
                <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{ obj.name }}</ng-template>
                <div class="tab-content" appContent>
                    {{ obj.name }}
                </div>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

I'm using below code to append to ContentComponent to the appContent, I'm not adding piece of code which create TagId and Array(Content) Mapping : -

```
  private tags: Array<Tag>;
  private currentTag: Tag;
  // private contents: Array<Content>;
  private tagContentsMap: Map<number, Array<Content>>;

  onTabChanged(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.currentTag = this.tags[event.index]; // fetching current tag from the Tags Array
    this.loadContentForTag(this.currentTag);
  }

  private loadContentForTag(tag: Tag) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ContentComponent);
    const viewContainerRef = this.contentsDirective.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    console.log(tag);
    console.log(this.tagContentsMap.get(tag.tagId)); // I can see content array here on tab change
    (<ContentComponent>componentRef.instance).contentList = this.tagContentsMap.get(tag.tagId); // On assigning content array here is not reflecting in the HTML of ContentComponent
  }
```

ContentComponent is as below: -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from '../../models/flat/content';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  template: `
  <p *ngFor="let content of contentList">
    {{ content.title }}
  </p>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  contentList: Array<Content>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

So now the problem is, tabs getting created dynamically and appContent vary with current Tab. For the First auto selected tab ContentComponent reflects the data in (div class="tab-content" appContent) but on changing tabs it's not reflecting data of the current tab's  even though anchor(appContent) is available.

Please help me resolve this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're complicating this a bit too much. I mean, why are you using dynamic components? You are always adding/removing the same component (`ContentComponent`). It would be much easier to just inject that component, and bind its `contentList` property to the content you want to show (I don't know the selector for `ContentComponent` os I', assuming it`s`content`):

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-tab-group class="tab-group" (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)">
            <mat-tab *ngFor="let obj of tags">
                <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{ obj.name }}</ng-template>
                <div class="tab-content" appContent>
                    <content [contentList]="tagContent"></content>
                    {{ obj.name }}
                </div>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Now, in the component:

```
private tags: Array<Tag>;
private currentTag: Tag;
private contentTag: Array<Content>;
// private contents: Array<Content>;
private tagContentsMap: Map<number, Array<Content>>;

onTabChanged(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.currentTag = this.tags[event.index]; // fetching current tag from the Tags Array
    this.tagContent = this.tagContentMap.get(this.currentTag.tagId);
}
```

As you see, much easier. You can also add an `ngIf` to the `<content ...></content>` tag so you can hide that component if `tagContent` is empty or `null` (don't know if this is possible)

Comment: You are beautiful baba, It worked perfectly fine. Thank you so much. I'm new to Angular silly mistakes teaching me a lot :)